# Python Class that Never Throws an AttributeError or TypeError

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7

What is the best way to implement a class that never throws an AttributeError or TypeError?

The idea is that I have a class like this

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = NeverThrowClass()
    def set_logger(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger
    def do_stuff(self)
        self.logger.info('Stuff is being done.')
        pass
```

Whenever certain class methods are classed, we write something to a log file. However if no log file was specified, I still want the class methods to function. I realize I could catch an exception whenever `self.logger` is accessed, but I would rather just have the default `logger` attribute be some magical `NeverThrowClass()` that will accept being called in anyway, and politely do nothing, and return `None` for any attribute value so that the class will still function fine whether a logger is specified or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```
class DoNothing(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return lambda *args, **kwargs: None
```

Basically, this class responds to any attribute access with a function that accepts any number of arguments and returns `None`.

```
logger = DoNothing()
logger.info("Stuff is being done")  # does nothing
```

Since it's using `__getattr__()` rather than the lower-level `__getattribute__()`, you can just throw some regular attributes on there if you want some non-method stuff.

```
class LoggerNot(DoNothing):
    loglevel = 0
```

Now you have a `loglevel` attribute that has a reasonable value (i.e. is not a function) if you have code that checks it.